# Complement of a set of measure zero is dense in $[a,b]$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Assume we have a subset of measure zero  $N$ in the Borel-$\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}([a,b])$.

I think that $[a,b]\setminus N$ is a dense set. But how to prove that?

My attempt:

let $x \in  [a,b]$ and $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary then $\lbrace z \in [a,b]: |x-z|<\varepsilon\rbrace \cap ([a,b]\setminus N)\neq \emptyset$ so there are infinitely many in any neighbourdhood. Hence it is dense, right?

The reason why the intersection is non-empty is if it would be empty, then $N\cup \lbrace z \in [a,b]: |x-z|\geq \varepsilon\rbrace = [a,b]$ so $\lambda(N\cup \lbrace z \in [a,b]: |x-z|\geq \varepsilon\rbrace )=b-a$ which is wrong for $\varepsilon>0$ hence we have a contradiction.

Comment: Your intuition seems to be correct, but I am unsure about exactly which definition of dense you want to use here. To me it seems like you want to use the fact that $N$ as a Borel set of measure $0$ can not contain any open ball. In my opinion, the most elegant way to prove your assertion from this fact would be using $[a,b]\setminus N$ is dense in $[a,b] \Leftrightarrow$ every open neighborhood $x \in U \subset [a,b]$ has nonempty intersection $U\cap ([a,b]\setminus N) \neq \emptyset$. To use this, pick any $n \in N$ and any open ball $B(n,\varepsilon)$. Now take a look at this Ball and $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct but the way you obtain a contradiction strikes me as somewhat awkward: I would just note that if $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \cap ([a, b] \setminus N) = \emptyset$, then $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \subseteq N$ (by definition of complement), and $\lambda((x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)) = 2\epsilon$, contradicting the fact that $\lambda(N) = 0$.